# How to identified unmatched value in list c#

Tags: c#, list

I have here a string output which comes from the server , i want to match that my output should be within the range of my given RangeValueList , any value outside the range , my program prints not matched and values match the list then it will print duration matched , but my current code always show me the message of duration matched no matter what value comes, any leads where my code is not working
Thanks

Here are the values

```
1.temp_initial = 00:02:34.964
2.temp_current = 00:02:36.972
```

**

```
            TimeSpan temp_initial = TimeSpan.Parse(_InitialTonKopfPosition);
            TimeSpan temp_current = TimeSpan.Parse(_CurrentTonKopfPosition);
            TimeSpan result = temp_current.Subtract(temp_initial);
            
            string output = result.ToString("g");
            Report.Info("Data", string.Format("Audio is played for '{0}' seconds", output));
            
            List<string> RangeValueList = new List<string>();
            RangeValueList.Add("0:00:01,997");
            RangeValueList.Add("0:00:01,998");
            RangeValueList.Add("0:00:01,999");
            RangeValueList.Add("0:00:02,000");
            RangeValueList.Add("0:00:02,001");
            RangeValueList.Add("0:00:02,002");
            RangeValueList.Add("0:00:02,003");
            RangeValueList.Add("0:00:02,004");
            RangeValueList.Add("0:00:02,005");
            RangeValueList.Add("0:00:02,006");
            RangeValueList.Add("0:00:02,007");
            RangeValueList.Add("0:00:02,008");
            RangeValueList.Add("0:00:02,009");
            //'0:00:02,008' 
                             
            int compareResult =0 ;
            foreach (string current in RangeValueList)
            {
                compareResult = String.Compare(current,output,StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
            }
            if(compareResult == 1)
                {
                    Report.Success("duration matched");
                }
                else
                {
                    Report.Failure("Not matched");
                }
            
           
            
        }
´´´
```

Comment: Please share the values of temp_initial and temp_current.

Comment: The way your code is written, what gets _reported_ us always the result of the last comparison. Is that what you want? Do you want to see if there are any matches? Do you want to see the result of a comparison to each of the values in the list? What do the entries in your list represent? If they are TimeSpans, why not have a `List<TimeSpan>` rather than a `List<string>`?

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad i have updated my post with the values.

Comment: @Flydog57 , i want to match my output with each value in the list and if it find a match my program prints "its a match" , else if does not than my program prints "not  matched".
The entries present the duration for audio play mode means for how much time audio has been played for e.g 00:00:01:997s etc etc
my output was a timespan but for formatting purpose i have used the string so i created the list of string also .

Comment: You are going to want to put the `if` statement within the `foreach` loop. Read your code. You loop over the list, calculating `compreResult` for each item in the list, but making only the last one be significant. Then you use that last one in your `if` statement logic

Comment: @Flydog57 as mentioned i dnt eant to make any value significant i want to compare my output value with values mentioned in the list, when i put my if condition in foreach loop it compare with each value and print did not matched and matched for the value its has been matched i dont want to print did not matched for each value but just once

Comment: Sorry, so you want to know if there is a match in any of the values in the list. Then, create a bool: `bool isAMatch=false:` before the loop. In the loop, if there is a match, set it to true. Then, after the loop, use that flag to determine if there was a match or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think it happens because you pass the `g` format specifier, which uses culture specific decimal separator, which may be `.` and not `,` in your system. You may want to use a custom format string instead.
2. If you want to check that the string value belongs to a certain collection of string, I think a `HashSet<string>` is the best class to deal with it.
3. Collection initialization can be simplified.

```cs
TimeSpan temp_initial = TimeSpan.Parse("00:02:34.964");
TimeSpan temp_current = TimeSpan.Parse("00:02:36.972");
TimeSpan result = temp_current.Subtract(temp_initial);

string output = result.ToString(@"h\:mm\:ss\,ffff");
Report.Info("Data", string.Format("Audio is played for '{0}' seconds", output));

var RangeValueList = new HashSet<string>
{
    "0:00:01,9970",
    "0:00:01,9980",
    "0:00:01,9990",
    "0:00:02,0000",
    "0:00:02,0010",
    "0:00:02,0020",
    "0:00:02,0030",
    "0:00:02,0040",
    "0:00:02,0050",
    "0:00:02,0060",
    "0:00:02,0070",
    "0:00:02,0080",
    "0:00:02,0090"
};

if (RangeValueList.Contains(output)) Report.Success("duration matched");            
else Report.Failure("Not matched");
```